# Redis client doesn't delete anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, redis

I'm using node.js [redis client](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis). Before I'm running unit tests I want to clear all redis keys. For some weird reasons my code does nothing.

```
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient({
  host: conf.host,
  port: conf.port,
  prefix: conf.prefix
});

client.on('connect', err => {
  // everything is OK here. I can set and get.
});

module.exports = redis;
```

Before tests are started I want to clear my cache:

```
const redis = require('file-above');

before(done => {
  redis.keys('*', function (err, rows) {
    rows.forEach(row => {
      console.log(row); // perfectly matched
      redis.del(row);
      // nothing changed. I can still get any of the rows above here
    });
  });
  done();
});
```

Nothing is deleted after this. I tried to add `setTimeout`, tried to use direct `redis.del('*', done)` without keys matching.

I can not find anything related to `.del` in `redis` package readme to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `flushall` if appropriate. See more documentation here http://redis.io/commands/FLUSHALL. In regards to your implementation though, I think you need to pass a callback to `del`.

Comment: Damn, callbacks in del solved my problem. Somewhere across net found info that .del is sync function. Ok, thanks for help

Comment: Unfortunately I was wrong. Nothing is changed. I can't use flushall cause it deletes more data than I want. Anyway thanks for help

Comment: If you're calling ``del`` in a loop you should either use ``async.js`` or promises

Comment: I've started to type "sure I do". Opened IDE to paste code snippet to question and found kinda stupid error in loop. It works, it works. Thank you for participation.

Comment: Use `sendCommand` in `node.js` to use the `flushall` command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using a prefix. So if you use keys function(from the docs it won't append any prefix ). But if you use the keys gotten from the keys function and use it to delete it'll append the prefix again. So you need to either create a new redis client without prefix option and use it or you can remove prefix in the keys array before calling del function.

For ex.
your prefix is **'TEMP:'**
If you use keys function with **'*'** it gets the keys ['TEMP:name','TEMP:age']

But in del function if you iterate the array what happens is the name of the key to be deleted becomes **'TEMP:TEMP:name'** as the redis adds aprefix to the del function, so the key is not deleted.

While iterating through the loop you can remove the prefix in the key array

```
const redis = require('file-above');

before(done => {
redis.keys('*', function (err, rows) {
rows.forEach(row => {
  console.log(row); //"TEMP:name"
  row.substr(yourRedisPrefix.length) //this will remove your key prefix from the row so the key name will be without prefix.  "name"
  redis.del(row); // here redis adds the prefix itself. "TEMP:name"
   });
  });
  done();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual implementation of `flushdb` or `flushall` commands in `redis` NPM package.

If you want to clear all `redis` keys in `node.js` you have to use `sendCommand`, like this:

```
    await redisClient.sendCommand(["FLUSHALL"]);
```

There is more information about this under the **Unsupported Redis Commands** section of [Redis NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis).